# initializing pre-allocated struct instances within a loop

Tags: c++, loops, struct, instance

I want to allocate  memory for a certain number of instances of a certain structure, using malloc().
Then, i want to initialize each instance within a loop.
But, for each iteration, i observ that the constructor, and the destructor just after, are called... why?
More suprising for me is the fact that each of my instance exists after the loop despite of the call of the destructor... and my instances are initialized with same values! 
I'm definitively missing something important... I would be grateful if someone can help me because for now, i can't explain what happen. 
Here is my C++ code :

```
struct myStruct{
   int* a;
   int* b;
   myStruct(int x, int y)
   {
    std::cout << "the constructor is called" << std::endl;
    a = (int*)malloc(x*sizeof(int));
    b = (int*)malloc(y*sizeof(float));
   }
   ~myStruct()
   {
       std::cout << "the destructor is called" << std::endl;
       delete[] a;
       delete[] b;
   } };

int main(int argc, char** argv){
int Nb = 3;
myStruct *S = (myStruct*)malloc(Nb*sizeof(myStruct));
for(int i=0 ; i<Nb ; i++)
{
    *(S+i) = myStruct(1,2);
}
std::cout << std::endl;
for(int i=0 ; i<Nb ; i++)
{
    std::cout << "instance " << i << " :" << std::endl;
    std::cout << (unsigned int)(*(S+i)->a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (unsigned int)(*(S+i)->b) << std::endl << std::endl;
}
system("PAUSE");}
```

My command window display :

the constructor is called

the destructor is called

the constructor is called

the destructor is called

the constructor is called

the destructor is called

instance 0 :
1608524712
4277075694

instance 1 :
1608524712
4277075694

instance 2 :
1608524712
4277075694

Press any key to continue . . .

Best Regards

Comment: You're allocating with `malloc` but freeing with `delete`? That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression

```
*(S+i) = myStruct(1,2)
```

what happens is that you create a **temporary** instance of your structure (the `myStruct(1,2)` part) then *copy* that instance to `S[i]`. The copy is shallow, and so only the pointers are copied and no new data is allocated or copied. After the expression is done the temporary instance is not needed anymore and so it destructed.

This destruction will of course cause the freeing of the data members, and so the pointers in the structure in the array (the copy) are no longer valid, and accessing them is undefined behavior. Also, you don't actually initialize the allocated memory to anything, so that memory will contain whatever was in there from before the allocation and the contents will seem random.

I suggest you read about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), and most importantly about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Joachim. In fact, i should use "new" instead of malloc. Here is my new constructor :  myStruct(int x, int y)
 {
  std::cout << "the constructor is called" << std::endl;
  a = new int[x];
  b = new int[y];
 } How do you think i can initialized my pre-allocated instancs of myStruct?

Comment: Ok, i understand the "rule of three" now! so i have to define an explicit copy constructor to be sure that when the destructor is called for my temporary instance, the data members of my instance will remain safe.

Comment: @LorentzLorentz Copy constructor _and_ copy assignment operator. And if your compiler is new enough, [rvalue reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors) versions of them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Each time through the loop the code creates a temporary object (`myStruct(1,2)`) then destroys it. That's what the output is showing.

That temporary object gets assigned to the uninitialized object `*(S+i)`, which is not a good thing. Objects should be initialized by a constructor, not an assignment operator. The way to use the constructor here is placement new:

```
new (S+i) myStruct(1,2);
```

The first value in parentheses is the address where the object will be constructed.

Having done that, as others have mentioned, you can't use `delete` on the resulting array because it wasn't created with `new`. So you'll have to loop through the objects and explicitly call the destructor on each one, then `free` the memory.

Comment: Thanks Pete. all right, with the placement "new", the destructor is not call anymore but instances are still initialized with the same values as my command window displays : the constructor is called
the constructor is called
the constructor is called

instance 0 :
3452816845
3452816845

instance 1 :
3452816845
3452816845

instance 2 :
3452816845
3452816845

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Sorry Pete, forget my last answer. It now perfecly works. Thanks you